# Installing the new Skype for Linux

Tags: software-installation, skype

*OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit*

I found out, there has been some development on the Microsoft end concerning Skype for Linux.

I would like to try it out, I prefer more of a CLI installation procedure than GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to download it:

```
wget --continue https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Then, there are more ways to install it, say I would prefer to solve dependencies, if there were any, during the installation, then I would probably go for `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

(Note #1: the `./` is very important here)

(Note #2: the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will not fill the file name for you)

This will resolve any dependencies for you.

---

Upgrading will go automatically through packages upgrades, because it adds the following file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

with contents:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

also meaning the new `skypeforlinux` is finally 64-bit.

---

Today's version is 8.x:

[image: Skype 8]